# Getting Started With PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have recently been getting into using Windows PowerShell. Does anyone know any good free resources to help me progress my learning and understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may always refer to `Get-Help about_`. This is really great resource from my perspective about the conceptual topics in PowerShell.

Also I would recommend checking http://www.powershell.org. There is a section with free books: https://leanpub.com/u/devopscollective and free videos: https://www.youtube.com/powershellorg.

Hope you enjoy it! :)

Answer (score 0):

## Videos

I highly recommend watching:

- [Getting Started with PowerShell 3.0](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/GetStartedPowerShell3)
- [Advanced Tools & Scripting with PowerShell 3.0](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/advpowershell3)

These are the videos which I remember watching long time ago on Microsoft Virtual Academy (currently decomissioned).

## Documentation

If you want to learn about specific cmdlet, check it's documentation. To find it you can either use [Get-Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help?view=powershell-7) or simply search for a cmdlet in your favourite search enging. I personally consider **Examples** section the most helpful.

On learn.microsoft.com you can also find `about_` topics mentioned in [Ivan Mirchev's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62549387/9902555).

<sub>**NOTE**: Be careful while checking the docs. Currently most of the articles are showing documentation for PowerShell 7. If you're using different version, there might be small (but annoying) differences.</sub>

Another site which I like a very much is [SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/https://stackoverflow.com/a/62549387/9902555) - it might be helpful for some of the basic cmdlets.

## Communities

Here's a list of communities which might be helpful if you seek any help:

- [StackOverflow PowerShell tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell)
- [/r/PowerShell](https://reddit.com/r/PowerShell/)
- [Microsoft PowerShell community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/powershell/ct-p/WindowsPowerShell)
- [PowerShell.org](https://powershell.org/) (already mentioned by Ivan)
- [Spiceworks PowerShell Forum](https://community.spiceworks.com/programming/powershell)

Answer (score 0):

This really helped me, I hope it helps you too. Good Luck.

https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/intro-to-powershell

Answer (score 0):

I would just get [Windows Powershell in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/windows-powershell-in-action-third-edition).  It's the most complete documentation/explanation of its intent.